# How can I set up Outlook 2010 to automatically save sent e-mails to a public folder so all of my coworkers can see them?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm trying to set up a public folder that sent e-mails can be viewed by multiple people. Help?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Exchange, you could setup a 2nd mailbox and then just Bcc or Cc that box.  Have the admin give certain users rights to read the box then they just have to add it in their settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot directly share your Sent Items folder with other people, then you couple create a duplicate public folder within your inbox and then create a rule to move sent mail to that folder.

The rule needs to be created from blank (may need to go to Manage Rules->New rule to get the full options)

Select 'Apply rule on messages I send'
Ignore conditions and click next & yes to apply to ALL sent items
Select 'move a copy to the specified folder' and specify your duplicate Sent Items folder and click next
Ignore exceptions (unless you want any) and click next
Name the rule, choose if you want to run it on existing sent items (could take a long time if you have lots) and finish.